# The iOS app crashed right after clicking the button on a UIAlertview

Tags: objective-c, ios

I tried to dial a number with the phone app after the user click on a button on a UIAlertview. The phone app did open, but the original app crashed right after clicking the button on the UIAlertview. Does anyone one know the reason? I did try to make sure I released everything that should be released. Thanks! Below is the code:

```
-(IBAction)dialButtonPressed:(UIButton *)numberButton
    {
    if ([company isEqualToString:@"Not Found"]==true){
            message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                              message:@"No replace number found. Would you like to dial anyway?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
            message.tag = 0;
            if(phoneLinkString)
            {
                [phoneLinkString release];
                phoneLinkString = nil;
            }
            [message show];
            [message autorelease];
            phoneLinkString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",replace]retain];


        }
    }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
        [self release];

        message = nil;


        if(message.tag == 0 && buttonIndex == 1){
            NSURL *phoneLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneLinkString];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneLinkURL];
        }

- (void)dealloc {
    [phoneNumberString release];
    [phoneNumberLabel release];
    [self release];
    [message release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The newest code

```
    -(IBAction)dialButtonPressed:(UIButton *)numberButton
            {
            if ([company isEqualToString:@"Not Found"]==true){
                    message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                                      message:@"No replace number found. Would you like to dial anyway?"
                                                                     delegate:self
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
                    message.tag = 1;
                    if(phoneLinkString)
                    {
                        [phoneLinkString release];
                        phoneLinkString = nil;
                    }
                    [message show];
                    [message autorelease];
                    phoneLinkString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",replace]retain];


                }
        }
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
        {

            if(message.tag == 1 && buttonIndex == 1){

                NSURL *phoneLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneLinkString];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneLinkURL];
                message = nil;
            }
        }
- (void)dealloc {
            [phoneNumberString release];
            [phoneNumberLabel release];
            [super dealloc];
        }
```

but it still crashed after clicking the button on the UIAlertview. The error is 0x3beb85b0:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8] EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7269634f) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: remove `[self release]` from every where and try

Comment: @rockstarberlin If you see code making calls to `retain`, `release`, or `autorelease`, then the project can't be using ARC.

Comment: I removed every [self release] and also removed message=nil before the if statement, but still doesn't work. Should I add anything? thanks!

Comment: Update your question by adding your newest code (but leave the original code). Also, tells us the error message and which line is causing the crash (based on the stack trace).

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be that you set your alert to nil before your if statement. Try putting it after.

Comment: Setting `message` to `nil` before the `if` statement is in no way causing the crash. It's still wrong, but not causing the crash.

Comment: Thnk you, you save my time :)

Answer (score 3):

The crash is happening due to this code. `[self release];`.
When you call `self` `release` the view in which the alert is displayed will released and deallocated, not the alertView. That's the cause of crash.

You are already releasing the alertViews memory in the `dialButtonPressed:` method using `[message autorelease];`

So no need to release the alertView again in `clickedButtonAtIndex`. So change the method like:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if(alertView.tag == 0 && buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSURL *phoneLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneLinkString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneLinkURL];
    }
    message = nil;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I added alertview = nil; and [alertView release]; in my clickedButtonAtIndex method and it resolved my issue. Thanks dude!

Comment: I did not ask the initial question. So I cannot accept it, can I?

Answer (score 2):

Your crash is being caused by poor memory management. The primary issue is calling `[self release]`. It's a pretty rare case that this is appropriate.

Another issue is your attempt to check the `message.tag` right after setting `message` to `nil`. Calling the `tag` property on a `nil` object will always result in a value of 0.

Your dealloc method is all wrong. Don't call `[self release]`. Don't call `[message release]` since you autoreleased it when you showed it.

BTW - never use a `tag` of 0. This is the default. If you want to use the `tag`, always use a non-zero value so you can distinguish the value from the default.

Comment: How can I user release in ios now?