# The iOS app crashed right after clicking on a UIAlertview

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The iOS app crashed right after clicking the button on a UIAlertview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409981/the-ios-app-crashed-right-after-clicking-the-button-on-a-uialertview)

I tried to dial a number with the phone app after the user click on a button on a UIAlertview. The phone app did open, but the original app crashed right after clicking the button on the UIAlertview. Does anyone one know the reason? I did try to make sure I released everything that should be released. The error is 0x3beb85b0: ldr r3, [r4, #8] EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7269634f) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! Below is the code:

```
    -(IBAction)dialButtonPressed:(UIButton *)numberButton
            {
            if ([company isEqualToString:@"Not Found"]==true){
                    message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                                      message:@"No replace number found. Would you like to dial anyway?"
                                                                     delegate:self
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
                    message.tag = 1;
                    if(phoneLinkString)
                    {
                        [phoneLinkString release];
                        phoneLinkString = nil;
                    }
                    [message show];
                    [message autorelease];
                    phoneLinkString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",replace]retain];


                }
        }
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
        {

            if(message.tag == 1 && buttonIndex == 1){

                NSURL *phoneLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneLinkString];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneLinkURL];
                message = nil;
            }
        }
- (void)dealloc {
            [phoneNumberString release];
            [phoneNumberLabel release];
            [super dealloc];
        }
```

Comment: Is it legal to retain value created on stack? Like here: phoneLinkString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",replace]retain];

Comment: Don't create exact duplicates of a question you posted the day before.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `didDismissWithButtonIndex`  instead of `clickedButtonAtIndex`. I am guessing let me know.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but apparently it still crashes with the same reason

Comment: Just tried that. Everything is ok on my simulator 5.1. so the problem is not with the alertView.